# Bullet only removing closest enemy

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection, monogame

I'm having an issue with my collision detection code. I'm making a top down shooter and when I shoot, the bullet will only destroy an enemy if it's the closest enemy. The bullet will go right through the 2nd closest enemy.

Here is my code:

```
// Iterate through bullets, if bullet ccollides with enemy, remove both
for (int i = 0; i < Bullet.Bullets.Count; i++)
{
    if (Collisions.IsColliding(
      (int)Bullet.Bullets[i].position.X, (int)Bullet.Bullets[i].position.Y, 
      Bullet.sprite.Width, Bullet.sprite.Height,
      (int)Enemy.Enemies[i].position.X, (int)Enemy.Enemies[i].position.Y, 
      Enemy.sprite.Width, Enemy.sprite.Height))
    {
        Enemy.Remove(Enemy.Enemies[i]);
        Bullet.Remove(i);
    }
}
```

And here is my is colliding method:

```
public static bool IsColliding(int x1, int y1, int w1, int h1, int x2, int y2, int w2, int h2)
{
    return x1 < x2 + w2 &&
           x2 < x1 + w1 &&
           y1 < y2 + h2 &&
           y2 < y1 + h1;
}
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: The expected behaviour is that the enemy and bullet is removed even if it isn't the closest to the player

Comment: What is `Bullet.Bullets`? What type of collection is it?

Comment: It's a list of `Bullets`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only checking th i-th bullet with the enemy of the same index and not with every enemy there is.

You should do something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < Bullet.Bullets.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Enemy.Enemies.Count; j++)
    {
        if (Collisions.IsColliding(
          (int)Bullet.Bullets[i].position.X, (int)Bullet.Bullets[i].position.Y, 
          Bullet.sprite.Width, Bullet.sprite.Height,
          (int)Enemy.Enemies[j].position.X, (int)Enemy.Enemies[j].position.Y, 
          Enemy.sprite.Width, Enemy.sprite.Height))
        {
            Enemy.Remove(Enemy.Enemies[j]);
            Bullet.Remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

This way you will check every bullet with every enemy, it's not the most efective way of doing it but it should work if you don't have tons of bullets and enemies at the same time.

Comment: This will still modify the collections based on indices while iterating through them. I'm not sure about c#, but this is potentially dangerous and prone to crashes and/or bugs and/or undefined behaviours.

Comment: **Face palm**... Should probably not write code at 3am then wake up at 8am for work. Thanks very much.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt called it. I get an argument is out of range exception when I shoot a bullet at any enemy but the closest it throws an exception. Here is the full code: https://gist.github.com/robbiewoods05/4661196fd2396db230d3

Comment: You could use a property which updates itself when an item is removed instead of Count if it exists (and also decrement i and j so you don't skip the bullet and enemy right after the ones that collided) or just terminate both loops when you get a collision. You could also set some deletion flag on colliding enemies and bullets and actually delete them after your whole loop has ended.

Comment: Thank you, adding `break;` after the removal code has fixed it.

Comment: No problem :)
But be aware that if you use break in there this code will find at most 1 collision per execution, so if you have many bullets and enemies at the same time some bullets may end up going right through the targets, if you don't want that to happen you should consider one of the other 2 solutions.

Comment: To fix this I'd usually do something like `Enemy.Enemies[i].IsDead = true;` and then after finishing iteration write `Enemy.Enemies.RemoveAll(e => { return e.IsDead;} );` so removals happen in a batch after we've found our collisions. One can also swap if order isn't important and you want to avoid copy costs of removing enemies early in the list.